# how to speed up group by count query for any subset of columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, group-by, rdbms

I am working on application for census data processing, it has about 10 criteria as collected info about every person(district, age, sex, maritalStatus, religion, ... and others), i decided to use Mysql, i created tables for every criteria and table "person" with columns as foreign keys on these criteria tables primary keys.

I need the possibility to GROUP BY any subset of these criteria columns on "person" table and to obtain total count for every combination.

I have about 3 million records, and foreign key columns of person table are indexed by default in InnoDB, time needed for some tests was about 10 seconds to 1 minute.

Because of allowing random set of columns grouping by it's impossible to use composite index, so MY QUESTION is how i can distinguish speed up performance in this kind of situation?

Example:
Schema: person(c1, c2, c3, c4, ...)
I need to do queries like:

```
SELECT c2,c4, count(*) FROM person GROUP BY c2, c4;
```

c2, c4 - i mean a random subset from all columns, not mandatory to start from c1, c2, ..., that would be easy to solve speedup performance with simple composite index, but it can be any random subset so i don't know what to use for speedup.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample queries that you want to speed up.  Otherwise, the question is just to broad:  "I have some data and some hypothetical queries.  How do I make them faster?"

Comment: Your queries are going to require a full table scan.  I don't see any simple options for speeding them up -- put the temporary table in memory, get better hardware, use a different database that supports parallel processing.

Comment: `i created tables for every criteria` Why not ONE table with all criteria and add proper relationship to then? One for each is really a bad design

Comment: first of all they differ from each other with some additional stuff, and second that they are just 10

Comment: because of small range of values for each criteria can bitmap index be a solution?

Comment: "use a different database that supports parallel processing." @GordonLinoff can you give me easiest example of such database or technique to distinguish parallelization for such query?

Answer (score 0):

It requires a full scan.  Period.  No index(es), no Foreign Keys, etc will help.

However...

If the table is bigger than be cached, you will be I/O-bound.  In *this* case, looking for way to shrinking the table or increasing RAM would be beneficial.

MySQL does not have "bitmap indexes".  Anyway, they probably would not help much.

10 criteria leads to 1023 combinations.  Not practical to do something with every one.

You mentioned Foreign Keys... Do not `JOIN` to the other table(s) in the query, rather do the `JOIN` after the `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`.  (This does a few lookups instead of millions.)